# Joi Validation: Is there a way to allow unknown keys for several schema objects in one go

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, joi

I have several validator files containing close to a hundred schema objects. I'd like to validate unknown keys for all of them at the same time. I have already figured out a way to validate unknown keys for one object which I have posted below. Is there a way to do it for all in one go? I'm looking for a DRY way to do this.

```
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
  a: Joi.string().required(),
  b: Joi.string().required()
}).unknown(true);

// or
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
  a: Joi.string().required(),
  b: Joi.string().required()
}).options({ allowUnknown: true })
```

Comment: But I'm not able to make API calls. I get this "\"c\" is not allowed" message without using the above rule.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [.defaults](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#defaultsmodifier) to create your own custom joi which in this case will have allowUnkown set true as default:

```
// Create your custom Joi
const customJoi = Joi.defaults((schema) => schema.options({
  allowUnknown: true 
}));

// schema using original Joi
const schema1 = Joi.object().keys({
  a: Joi.string().required(),
  b: Joi.string().required()
})

// schema using custom Joi
const schema2 = customJoi.object().keys({
  a: Joi.string().required(),
  b: Joi.string().required()
})
 
// INVALID, "c" is not allowd
schema1.validate({ a: "a", b: "b", c: 10 })
// VALID
schema2.validate({ a: "a", b: "b", c: 10 })
```

This also works:

```
var Joi = require("joi").defaults((schema) => schema.options({
  allowUnknown: true 
}));
```

or

```
var Joi = require("joi")
Joi = Joi.defaults((schema) => schema.options({
  allowUnknown: true 
}));
```

Comment: This solution is no different from the one I posted in the question. I will still have to edit all schema objects with the customJoi. Is there a universal setting that I can set once and forget about?

Comment: You don't need to edit all your schemas as long as you keep the original Joi name that you are currently using. You just need to update the headers to load your custom Joi.